# 周波数を1次元配列にして出力する際、計算が異常に重くなる

Tags: julia

０~1を例えば１０万の目盛りでわけたいときに、以下のコードだとものすごく重くなってしまいます。

```
function fs()
    Fs = Float64[]
    for i in 1:time
        push!(Fs,i/time)
    end
end
```

もっと軽快に動く書き方はありますでしょうか

Answer (score 1, accepted):

質問の趣旨からは離れますが、julia では BenchmarkTools パッケージを利用してベンチマークテストを実施することができます。

まず、fs 関数を以下の様に定義しておきます。

```julia
function fs(time)
  Fs = Float64[]
  for i in 1:time
    push!(Fs, i/time)
  end
  return Fs
end
```

この fs 関数と `range() + collect()` での処理のベンチマークテストを行ってみます。

```julia
julia> using BenchmarkTools
julia> x = @benchmark fs(10^5)
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  memory estimate:  2.00 MiB
  allocs estimate:  17
  --------------
  minimum time:     600.405 μs (0.00% GC)
  median time:      604.940 μs (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        613.886 μs (0.00% GC)
  maximum time:     1.098 ms (0.00% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          7819
  evals/sample:     1

julia> y = @benchmark collect(range(0.0, stop=1.0, length=10^5))
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  memory estimate:  781.33 KiB
  allocs estimate:  2
  --------------
  minimum time:     276.665 μs (0.00% GC)
  median time:      277.874 μs (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        291.672 μs (4.08% GC)
  maximum time:     40.080 ms (99.30% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     1
```

平均(mean)実行時間を比較してみます。

```julia
julia> using Statistics
julia> ratio(mean(y), mean(x))
BenchmarkTools.TrialRatio: 
  time:             0.47512421388811227
  gctime:           Inf
  memory:           0.3813536701620591
  allocs:           0.11764705882352941
```

実行時間は半分程度になりますが、`collect(range(...))` では GC(Garbage Collection)が発生していて、その場合は 40ms も掛かってしまっていることが判ります(実行環境や実行時の状況によりけりでしょうけれども)。

その他の手法があればベンチマークを実行して比較してみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: すこし難しい話ですが、非常に有益な助言、誠にありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1):

自前でループを書くと遅くなりがちなので、ブロードキャストなどを利用するのが良いです。

```
len=100000
Fs = collect(1:len)
Fs /= len
```

あるいは、誤差が出る可能性に目をつむれば、

```
Fs = collect(1/len:1/len:1)
```

は、もうほんの少し速いと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます！参考にさせていただきます！